# Software used for modelling quantum processors

Tags: programming, resource-request, experimental-realization

What kind of software is used for modelling quantum processor architectures? Not just simulate the output, but the one that is actually used in research.

Comment: Look up software used by companies who have actual physical prototypes, such as Qiskit by IBM or Pyquil by Rigetti. When using their simulators, you can specify such features as qubit topology and noise models.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use simulators in web-interfaces of quantum processors providers. Here are links to the providers offering their platforms for free:

- [IBM Q Experience](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/)
- [QuTech Quantum Inspire](https://www.quantum-inspire.com/projects)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something that simulates the actual hardware, or something that runs quantum circuits?

If you're looking for circuit simulation with the widest variety of possible operations, the closest thing we can do on a classical computer is Density Matrix simulation.

- [quantumsim](https://gitlab.com/quantumsim)
- [cirq](https://github.com/quantumlib/cirq)

are two that I've used, but others are also out there.

If you actually want to simulate the physics happening on the hardware level, the question is very hardware specific.